# JointJS: Hello World example doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jointjs

I am always seeing this exception when I try the Hello World example from the JointJS site:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'getStrokeBBox' of undefined
```

Here's the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<!--
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/joint.css" />
<script src="js/joint.js"></script>
-->


<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://www.jointjs.com/downloads/joint.css"></link>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.jointjs.com/downloads/joint.js" ></script>


<script>
    var graph = new joint.dia.Graph;

    var paper = new joint.dia.Paper({
        el: $('#myholder'),
        width: 600,
        height: 200,
        model: graph
    });

    var rect = new joint.shapes.basic.Rect({
        position: { x: 100, y: 30 },
        size: { width: 100, height: 30 },
        attrs: { rect: { fill: 'blue' }, text: { text: 'my box', fill: 'white' } }
    });

    var rect2 = rect.clone();
    rect2.translate(300);

    var link = new joint.dia.Link({
        source: { id: rect.id },
        target: { id: rect2.id }
    });

    graph.addCells([rect, rect2, link]);
</script>
</head>
<title>Test</title>

<body>
    <div id="myholder"> </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I saw that there is another question already asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21233427/newbie-hello-world-using-jointjs) for the same problem, but the solution given there isn't relevant as I already have a div element for paper object.

Comment: Move your `<script>` block to the end of the `<body>`. When it runs as it stands now, that `<div>` will not be in the DOM yet so the code won't work.

Comment: yes it works... thanks!  Why not post it as an answer? ;-)

Comment: possible duplicate of [hello world does not work properly in html with jointjs?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21271801/hello-world-does-not-work-properly-in-html-with-jointjs)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
el: $('#myholder'),
```

Browsers read from top to bottom.  The browser is executing this line before it ever finds an element with the id of `myholder`, so `el` is an empty jQuery object.

Instead, move your script tag to the bottom of the HTML (so the browser has found `myholder` before you try to grab it) or wrap it all in a [`$(document).ready(` call](http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/).

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to get elements which are not created yet. Place your script at the end of `<body>` or use `$(document).ready();`

Answer (score 1):

you are <del>not</del> using jQuery so this will work:

```
window.onload = function () {   your entire javascript code here };
```

but better include jQuery.js too and use:

```
$(function () {  your entire javascript code here  });
```

The code is executed line by line so it first loads and runs your javascript and doesn't know what "myholder" is. Doing it like I explained above it will load the javascript but it will only execute it  once the entire page is loaded.